# PHP SoapClient: отправка таблицы данных

Tags: php, soap

Нужно передать на сервер таблицу со значениями `id` продуктов и их количеством. В формате:

```
<ns1:Products>
    <ns2:Row>
        <ns2:ProductCode>string</ns2:ProductCode>
        <ns2:Amount>int</ns2:Amount>
    </ns2:Row>
    <ns2:Row>
        <ns2:ProductCode>string</ns2:ProductCode>
        <ns2:Amount>int</ns2:Amount>
    </ns2:Row>
    ...
</ns1:Products>
```

Проблема в том, что не получается задать несколько значений `Row`.
Рабочий вариант получился такой:

```
$row = array();
$row['ProductCode'] = 'test';
$row['Amount'] = 1;

$products['Row'] = $row;
```

Но если передавать `$products['Row']` как массив с различными `$row`, то уже не работает.
Аналогичная ситуация с `stdClass`...

Подскажите, как решить проблему?

**upd...**

Тип продукта:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://195.234.212.206/order" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://195.234.212.206/order" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:complexType name="ProductRow">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ProductCode" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Amount" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ProductTable">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Row" type="tns:ProductRow"/>
            </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Передаю так:

```
$params = array(
    /* Другие параметры */
    'Products' => array (
            'Row' => array (
                    'ProductCode' => 1212,
                    'Amount' => 1
                )

        )

);

$client->__SoapCall('OrderClient', array('parameters' => $params));
```

**Решено**
Проблема была в wsdl

Answer (score 1):

А просто вот так не пробовали

```
$products[]=$row;
```

Comment: Пробовал. Так ругается на отсутствие свойства Row у объекта.

Comment: а код приведите что там у вас написано, и еще бы на wsdl глянуть